# Need help identifying this Specialized bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

Looking to purchase this bike, but wanted to verify what kind of specialized bike it is. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's a [2018 Women's Specialized Sirrus Disc](https://www.evanscycles.com/specialized-sirrus-disc-2018-womens-hybrid-bike-ex-demo-ex-display-m-EV325238).

Also [here, on the Specialized site](https://www.specialized.com/gb/en/sirrus-womens-spec/p/171213?color=264670-171213)

[image]